# Finding the execution time of a program in pascal

Tags: syntax, pascal, subroutine, execution-time

I want to find the execution time of a program I wrote in pascal but i dont know the syntax to do that.. is there a function that calculates it? I searched a little bit and found that people use the type TDateTime and give to a var the value now and to another var the value now (one before the program that we want to have its execution time and one after) and then calculate the difference between the two values. But I cant really do that because I would need the DateUtils lib (which i dont have??).. Is there another way to calculate the execution time??

(I'm using windows 10)

Comment: If you want to measure the time the _entire_ program takes, you’ll need to use an _external_ program such as [`time`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_%28Unix%29). Did you mean you want to measure the time a _subroutine_ takes?

Comment: yes I meant the execution time of a subroutine not the entire program..

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: Please locate the **Edit** button beneath the tags of your question and edit your question to make it clear, that you want to measure the execution time of a subroutine. Also include the requested OS information.

Answer (score 1):

Use the unit [`SysUtils`](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/sysutils/index-5.html) and from that the [`Now()`](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/sysutils/now.html) function - it will give you the current date and time. Call it once before and once after whatever you want to measure. Since [`TDateTime` is in fact only a `Double`](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/system/tdatetime.html) you can operate arithmetically on it (subtraction) - that way you can later just pull each time (and date) component to see how long it lasted:

```pascal
program TimeDiff;

uses
  SysUtils;  // Every Pascal implementation should have this

// Just pointless calculations to waste CPU cycles
function RoutineToMeasure(): Integer;
var
  i, j: Integer;
begin
  result:= 0;
  for i:= 0 to $7FFFFFFF do begin
    j:= i div 24;
    j:= j+ 10;
    result:= result xor j;
    result:= result or i;
  end;
end;

// The actual program to measure times
var
  tStart, tEnd, tDiff: TDateTime;  // Begin and end of measurement, and difference
  iHours, iMinutes, iSeconds, iMilliseconds: Word;  // Time components
begin
  tStart:= Now();  // Get date+time
  RoutineToMeasure();
  tEnd:= Now();  // Get date+time again

  // To be read by a human
  Writeln( '  started: ', DateTimeToStr( tStart ) );
  Writeln( ' finished: ', DateTimeToStr( tEnd ) );

  // Calculating the actual time it took
  tDiff:= tEnd- tStart;  // Subtract higher from lower value
  DecodeTime( tDiff, iHours, iMinutes, iSeconds, iMilliseconds );  // Does not account for day changes when executing around midnight
  Writeln( '    taken: ', iHours, ' h, ', iMinutes, ' min, ', iSeconds, ' sec, ', iMilliseconds, ' msec' );

  Readln();
end.
```

Successfully tested in Lazarus 2.2.0 with FCP 3.2.2; the output is as per a 4 core 3.2 GHz CPU:

> ```
>   started: 2022-12-14 14:33:07
>  finished: 2022-12-14 14:33:12
>     taken: 0 h, 0 min, 5 sec, 323 msec
> ```